# Need batch script to copy latest build folder including subfolder into local

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, build, scripting

I tried this but it's not working:

```
SET src_path ="\\xyz\abc"
SET tgt_path ="c:\MyNightlyBuyild"
FOR /F "delims=|" %%I IN ('DIR "%src_path%" /B /O:D /S') DO SET NewestFile=%%I
Xcopy "%NewestFile%" "%tgt_path%"
```

Comment: what was the error?

Comment: SET src_path=\\xyz\abc
SET tgt_path=c:\MyNightlyBuyild
FOR /F "delims=|" %%I IN ('DIR "%src_path%" /B /O:D /S') DO SET NewestFile=%%I
Xcopy "%NewestFile%" "%tgt_path%"                                                          I edited as you mentioned but its still not copying the folder

Comment: There is no error .. Its executes without any error

Answer (score 0):

This batch code saved with Windows Notepad with **ANSI** encoding selected in the Save As dialog worked fine on execution from within a command prompt window to see possible output error messages:

```
SET "src_path=\\Server\Share\My Folder"
SET "tgt_path=C:\Temp"
FOR /F "delims=" %%I IN ('DIR "%src_path%" /B /O:D /S') DO SET "NewestFile=%%I"
XCOPY "%NewestFile%" "%tgt_path%"
```

Of course I have had with my user account the permissions to traverse the directories on the specified server share and read the file found recursively in `\\Server\Share\My Folder`.

But saving the same batch code with *Unicode* encoding selected resulting in storing the file as UTF-16 LE with BOM file results in execution from within command prompt window in the error message:

> '■' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

The error message is also output on double clicking the batch file, but the command process is in this case automatically closed in comparison to run the batch file from within a command prompt window.

Note 1: Always save batch files as **ANSI** encoded files on using Windows Notepad.

Note 2: Always test batch files from within a command prompt window to see error messages.

Comment: I executed the mention batch code. but it did not give me expected result. It copied only one file but i wanted to copy the latest folder including sub folder with content.

Comment: @Ricky_123 Sorry, but I can't help if you don't know what you want or can't describe what you want. The command __DIR__ with the parameters `/B /O:D /S` lists all non hidden and non system files/directories in bare format recursively ordered by date with oldest file/directory at top and newest file/directory at bottom. Run this command from within a command prompt window to see the list and run also `dir /?` or `help dir` for help on this command. If you want something different, you need other options and perhaps additionally other code in body of __FOR__.